# Image Saving explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, streaming, filestream

I have manage to write images on an sql server 2008

But i see that in the image record writing the same bytes in all of the images

And also it creates on the remote disk under a special catalogue a file which finally is the image

Is there anybody which can explain me the flow chart of writing an image in sql server?

What is contained in the image record?

Comment: It is really hard to help because we have no idea even what language you are using to pass your image data into SQL Server.  Are you using a VARBINARY column, IMAGE, NVARCHAR, ...?  Have you visited any tutorials that walk you through this (e.g. http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/ImageToSqlServer11242006025136AM/ImageToSqlServer.aspx)?  You need to include more details (e.g. what you tried) as pave_m suggested in order to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: Or are you using FILESTREAM?  If so, what code have you tried?  Also, please be sure that you actually want to store your image data directly in SQL Server.  There are pros and cons to doing so but in every case I've encountered thus far, we have always used the file system for the image data, and stored the path and/or URL in the database.

Comment: Dear Aaron thank you very much for your intent in my question.-
I'm programming in VB.NET with visual studio 2010, and i'm using FILESTREAM with varbinary(max).-
But my issue is NOT how to handle this procedure (because i have already done this).-
My question is pointing of WHAT THE SQL BASE PUTING ON HER image RECORD.-
And WHAT IS WRITTEN ON THE FILE under the shared folder (this is a special file).-
Tha is what i want to know.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of tutorials on saving image data in a FILESTREAM column in SQL Server 2008:

http://blogs.msdn.com/rdoherty/archive/2007/10/12/getting-traction-with-sql-server-2008-filestream.aspx

http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/sql-server-2008-filestream-part-1-of-3-introducing-filestream/

http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/sql-server-2008-filestream-part-2-of-3-enabling-and-using-filestream/

http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/sql-server-2008-filestream-part-3-of-3-using-the-opensqlfilestream-api/

Comment: Dear Aaron
You are much much close to what i'm seeking to find.-
That i was seeking to find was the mentality of the FILESTREAM stracture.-
Means "why we put that here" and "why we give this to that"
Thank you